# Django Error: 'function' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-apps

Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Model.py

```
class Cattest(models.Model):
category = models.ForeignKey(Category)    
info = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
```

form.py

```
class CattestForm(forms.Form):
autocomplete = forms.CharField(
    label='Type the name of a category (AutoCompleteWidget)',
    widget=selectable.AutoCompleteWidget(CategoryLookup),
    required=False,
)
info = forms.CharField(max_length=35, label="Information")
```

view.py

```
def cattest(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CattestForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cattest.save()        
else:
    if request.GET:
        form = CattestForm(initial=request.GET)
    else:
        form = CattestForm()
return render_to_response('bsmain/form.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Traceback:

AttributeError at /bsmain/cattest/

'function' object has no attribute 'save'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/bsmain/cattest/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:

'function' object has no attribute 'save'

Exception Location:     /home/bill/workspace/boatsite/../boatsite/bsmain/views.py in cattest, line 50
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.5

Comment: Don't you want to call .save() on the model referenced by the form, and not the view function itself?

Answer (score 3):

You have a type-o in  your view.

you are calling `save()` on the function you are in `cattest.save()` 
I think this should be on the form??  You might want to look at `ModelForm` it provides a form that maps directly to your model, which it looks like you are doing.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm

The form you are using is just a normal form and doesn't have a save method. After subclassing ModelForm you can then call save on a form instance.

```
if your_form.is_valid():
  your_form.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling save method on function itself. That is the reason behind the error. if you are looking for form to save then:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

Answer (score -1):

`class CattestForm(forms.Form):` should be `class CattestForm(forms.ModelForm):`

Comment: We would love to see some explanation to go together with your answer. Would you be able to explain why do you think this will solve the problem, please?